# How to make Discriminated Unions work with destructuring?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider the following three types in which `MainType` is union of `Type1` and `Type2`. If `kind` is `"kind1"` then `data` should be of type `{msg: string}` same from `Type2`

```
interface Type1 {
    kind: "kind1";
    data: { msg: string };
}
interface Type2 {
    kind: "kind2";
    data: { msg2: string };
}

type MainType = Type1 | Type2;
```

Here is the first way to use it.

```
function func(obj: MainType) {
    switch (obj.kind) {
        case "kind1": return obj.data.msg;
        case "kind2": return obj.data.msg2;
    }
}
```

The above code gives no error and shows correct autocomplete.

But when we destructure the `obj` then it gives error.

```
function func({kind, data}: MainType) {
    switch (kind) {
        case "kind1": return data.msg;
        case "kind2": return data.msg2;
    }
}
```

The error is

> Property `'msg'` does not exist on type `'{ msg: string; } | { msg2: string; }'`

Maybe its something very basic. But I am new to ts so I can't get how destructuring changes the types. Please explain the reason and also tell is there any way to fix it.

Answer (score 14):

By using destructuring at level of function argument we loose connection between `kind` and `data`. So switch by `kind` is not narrowing the `data` as now they are in different data structures.

I can say you remove the bound between `kind` and `data` what means that you really introduce two variables, one with type `kind1 | kind2` and second with type `{ msg: string; } | { msg2: string; }`.

In result we don't have discriminant in form of `kind` anymore.

Below equivalent code to destructuring behavior:

```
const f = (t: MainType) => {
  const kind = t.kind // "kind1" | "kind2";
  const data = t.data // {msg: string;} | {msg2: string;}
}
```

And yes from the logic perspective your code is fully ok, it should work as we know the relation between these fields. Unfortunately TS is not able to understand the bound.

**In summary** - unfortunate until your don't narrow the type to specific member of the union, you cannot use destructuring, as it will ruin the type relationship between fields.

---

We can think about **workaround** by some type guards. Consider following example:

```
const isKind1 = (kind: MainType['kind'], data: MainType['data']): data is Type1['data'] 
=> kind === 'kind1'
const isKind2 = (kind: MainType['kind'], data: MainType['data']): data is Type2['data'] 
=> kind === 'kind2'

const f = ({kind, data}: MainType) => {
  if (isKind1(kind, data)) {
    data // is { msg: string }
  }
  if (isKind2(kind, data)) {
    data // is { msg2: string }
  }
}
```

By using type guards `isKind1` and `isKind2` we are able to create a connection between these two variables. But the issue is we cannot use `switch` anymore, we also have more code, and field relation implemented in functions and not type definitions, such approach is error prone as I can do different relation in function then the original type is defining.

To be clear I am showing it is possible but its not worth the candle and I suggest to keep the original implementation without destructuring.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, TypeScript officially fixed this problem in [v4.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/#cfa-aliased-conditions), and now you can use deconstruction with confidence!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You can see the documentation here: [Control Flow Analysis of Aliased Conditions and Discriminants](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/#cfa-aliased-conditions)

Comment: Why doesn't it work in my case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73251532/why-typescript-cannot-infer-discriminated-types-when-destructing

Comment: This should be the correct answer nowadays!
One thing to note: this does not seem to work when destructuring a function parameter, e.g. a prop of a react component. In that case one has to do the destructuring inside the component.