# Typescript throws error when accessing payload in reducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, reducers

I have a reducer in which **Typescript** throws an error if I try to access **formError** property in the **payload** in the **second switch case**.

```
import actionTypes, { ActionCreatorType, ReducerType } from './types';

const initialState: ReducerType = {
  formError: '',
  responseSubmitted: false,
};

const enquiryFormReducer = (state = initialState, action: ActionCreatorType): ReducerType => {
  const { type, payload, } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case actionTypes.SUBMIT_FORM_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        responseSubmitted: true,
        formError: '',
      };

    case actionTypes.SUBMIT_FORM_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        responseSubmitted: false,
        formError: payload.formError,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default enquiryFormReducer;
```

This is my **types** file.

```
const actionTypes = {
  SUBMIT_FORM_SUCCESS: 'SUBMIT_FORM_SUCCESS',
  SUBMIT_FORM_FAILURE: 'SUBMIT_FORM_FAILURE',
} as const;

interface FormErrorType {
  formError: string;
}

export interface SuccessActionType {
  type: typeof actionTypes.SUBMIT_FORM_SUCCESS;
  payload: {};
}

export interface FailureActionType {
  type: typeof actionTypes.SUBMIT_FORM_FAILURE;
  payload: FormErrorType;
}

export interface ReducerType {
  responseSubmitted: boolean;
  formError: string;
}

export type ActionCreatorType = | SuccessActionType | FailureActionType;

export default actionTypes;
```

You can see that the actionCreatorTypes is a union of all the actions are possible as per the switch case. But **Typescript** throws following error:

```
Property 'formError' does not exist on type '{} | FormErrorType'.
Property 'formError' does not exist on type '{}'
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is destructuring. When you do so `type` stops be related to `payload` and not works as union discriminant anymore. Please use `action.type` and `action.payload` directly.

```
switch (action.type) { // direct use
    case actionTypes.SUBMIT_FORM_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        responseSubmitted: false,
        formError: action.payload.formError, // direct use
      };
    ...
```

Comment: Hi, Maciej I did try ```formError: action.payload.formError``` but that didn't work as well.

Comment: have you done `switch(action.type)` and inside `action.payload.formError` ?

Comment: Put you additional snippet in the answer

Comment: Hey Maciej, I forgot to change ```switch(type)``` to ```switch(action.type)```and now it works perfectly fine. It will be really great if you could explain a little bit in depth why destructuring causes issue as I am unable to understand that :) Thanks again!

Comment: Take a look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59786104/how-to-make-discriminated-unions-work-with-destructuring/59786171#59786171