# Typescript discriminated union type inference with destructuring

Tags: typescript, type-inference, destructuring, discriminated-union

Given a discriminated union:

```js
type ViewModel<T> =
  | { state: State.LOADING,   model: undefined }
  | { state: State.READY,     model: T         }
  | { state: State.NOT_FOUND, model: null      }
```

This form of type inference works:

```js
switch (viewModel.state) {
  case State.LOADING:
    viewModel.model; // undefined
    break;
  case State.READY:
    viewModel.model; // Foo
    break;
  case State.NOT_FOUND:
    viewModel.model; // null
    break;
}
```

but this one doesn't (only difference is the object destructuring):

```js
const { state, model } = viewModel;
switch (state) {
  case State.LOADING:
    model; // Foo | null | undefined
    break;
  case State.READY:
    model; // Foo | null | undefined
    break;
  case State.NOT_FOUND:
    model; // Foo | null | undefined
    break;
}
```

What I like to know is:

1. Is this working as intended or is it a shortcoming in current typescript implementation?
2. If this is working as intended, could one show us an example where this would break?

Additional reading:

- [typescript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=33&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgQzsKBvKAZA8gQQCICSAcgOIA0UASgKL4CaFRWAKgPoBiWAqkXlAL4AoOAE8ADigBqAS2AB3ALIB7ACbAANgB5mAPigBeQVCgAfNFADOiZAC5Y14ADps+YuSgRVGu2BBqAZtIgwCoCRqbmVkjAdvDRjjT0FJ5q6nbMYcZm6FG29vFMbJw8eMleaVDg6uphohJQ7EpKBub+TXYA5ABGCABOHQIA3IJqAMbqfSijSiBWUABusorldjLyyqmajUo6w4IWctJwowAWUAAUi+vljrnAAJRo4aMIFihxyM64hKQ24cZXZapRwpDSDKAAeghUF8ASCIX+UC6vWACAA1sNjC83vlPok8HQ-sYAUsNhoQeVwVCGk1EcjURjnq93g5HIUONxeETiYCyeoKakqdCquo6Sj0cMhIJprM4JEHGVUgIWrzKftDsczuc7o9UEycR8nC4fiRucZQeohTTmmYRRFYcBAsEVGKGZioNiWfF8YTERardsInazA6nQjiUjxYysczcU52cUuX7KZDoYHbWBqva-I74S6I-SJYIhEA)
- [typescript docs on discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions).

Comment: Yes discriminator doesn't work after destructuring

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Discriminated Unions work with destructuring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59786104/how-to-make-discriminated-unions-work-with-destructuring)

Comment: @MaciejSikora [the destructuring example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59786171/12644421) in plain javascript example helps somewhat. What's still unclear to me is: can this be overcome by typescript or is this problem fundamentally unsolveable?