# How do I assign a value to a conditional type?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function such that the first parameter is `boolean`, and depending on whether this argument is `true` or `false`, the second argument is a function that accepts either a `string` or `string[]`.

Here is my attempt:

```js
type P<B extends boolean> = B extends true ? string[] : string

function callback<B extends boolean>(b: B, t: (f: P<B>) => void) {
    const file = 'file'
    if (b) {
        t([file]) // <-- Error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'P<B>'.
    } else {
        t(file)   // <-- Error: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'P<B>'.
    }
    
}

callback(false, (f: string) => {})  // <-- No problem, resolves the correct argument type
callback(true, (f: string[]) => {}) // <-- No problem, resolves the correct argument type
```

This works for resolving the correct argument types when the function is called. However, inside the function, the TS compiler is giving me an error that it cannot resolve the conditional type to either `string` or `string[]`. What is the correct way to do this?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgPAIShAHsCA7AJgZygIwHtCAbCAQwwD4oBeKJVdbPYAJwFdoB+KHdgJYYA5gG0AulABcfQSICwAKCUAzDhgDGwAYQxQN5EiXzkNAa0TI0mXAWJlKVABT4ZCADRRgMpypnwEKgBKOhoAN0IBLBCAbyUoBP1dfigVATI6KAByNLIs+MSBFSgXWILExOAnUVyIcSDyqABfZBIcaDjFCoqq2oauxKbGpSHlRQMjE3NfQ3bPXxl+NiFhENoaGKagoA).

Comment: Currently it is not possible to narrow one parameter (`t`) by testing another one (`b`)

Comment: I wonder how best to do this with TS, then. Seems like conditional types are made for this. It's odd that it correctly types the call, but not the values inside the function.

Comment: Overloads are the way to go here I think

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky, the problem is that you have 2 variables and the type of one of them depends on another: typescript can't handle this. Also you may know that it can't handle destructured discriminated unions: it can't infer the type of one variable depending on another one

Comment: @AlexChashin thanks a lot. I am trying to dive a bit into these more advanced types and am pretty new to them still.

Comment: @AlekseyL. thank you. Yes, I think overloads might be the way to go especially since in reality the boolean argument in my case will be optional with a default. So, perfect for an overload?

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky, you may take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59786104/how-to-make-discriminated-unions-work-with-destructuring, there they discuss a similar problem with two variables that should be connected but they actually aren't

Comment: This doesn't help to solve your problem, just in case you're interested

Comment: Still ugly with overloads https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAhgGzQIxRA1gCkwC5EoAnEAUwBpST9gSBncmMAcwG0BdASkQC8APkQA3ODAAmvEuKkBYAFChIsBMnRYcBYomDomNOogbNWHfsLETpsm0pXR4SVBmx58AOm8oy7JiSc5FS0pogsZGxcfIIicpLciAA+iJz6aIahjOHm7JZxNjEA3kqIZcgILHowaJSCiADkwDWUDaXlMMAmvv6cAAzF7eXlPUycAIzc+GktfEOIAL6IlBl1JYrDw6MTU821vPMLSgtAA

Comment: Yeah that's pretty bad, thank you. Probably the way to go is an object param as several answers describe. Not sure about using a typeguard as Krzysztof Krzeszewski mentions because even though it's nice it's kind of odd.

Comment: The compiler is notoriously bad at verifying that something is assignable to a conditional types that depends on unspecified generic type parameters.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for the specific issue about function return types, but it's the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it by passing an object with both parameters. By using a type that has `true` and the one signature or `false` and the other, the compiler can differentiate the object by testing the `b` property.

```
type f = { b: false, t: (f: string) => void };
type t = { b: true, t: (f: string[]) => void };
type fOrT = f | t;

function callback(x: fOrT) {
    const file = 'file'
    if (x.b) {
        x.t([file])
    } else {
        x.t(file)
    }
    
}

callback({ b: false, t: (f: string) => {} })
callback({ b: true, t: (f: string[]) => {} })
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAZlC8UDeUBGAuWBDANgZwgBophMAKGTPYAJwEsA7AcwEoEA+KANwHs6ATKAF8A3AChQkEgmRpMtAK5ES5SlGr1mAbQC6beJ14Dh4ydBgB5GgBUZcAD4lxYmAoYBjYHR4Mo73DioWO4A1mQAHpiWNmxIYlAJfj7UsHQ40IgA5DBpEJnxiXRwEQB0qLEFiYnhJcBkWjnpepXCUBD40HFVVTV1jRAsLUItYsNi-jiBwWFIGDC4BMSkFFS0jKwcyEJCgxNToWSz8jRKS+gr6mvaeptI2yxAA)

Comment: Thank you! This seems like a very TS way (using object structure) to do it. I will consider doing it like this.

Comment: Note, this works because `fOrT` is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions), for which control flow analysis can be used to narrow to useful types.

Answer (score 2):

You can narrow a type down based on another variable by writing custom typings, for instance

```
function instanceOfMyTYpe(textArray: string[] | string, flag: boolean): textArray is string {
    return flag;
}

let file = "test" as string | string[];
file.toUpperCase(); // doesn't work. Property 'toUpperCase' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'.
if (instanceOfMyTYpe(file, true)) file.toUpperCase(); // but this works
else file.forEach((text)=>text.toUpperCase()); // and so does this
```

It will not link one variable with another, so invalid function calls can stil happen. For instance calling the function with an array and true flag, will make your program think that the array is actually a string, even though it isn't so be careful.

Comment: Thank you. So the code as written in my question will work for typing the caller, and then I can use such a type guard inside the function?

Answer (score 1):

Using generic type arguments like this is a real pain in the neck, I'm not sure how this works exactly, but you can almost never make typescript narrow down the types. If you hover over `t` inside the `if` construct, you will see, that it has type `(f: P<B>) => void`, not `(f: string) => void` or `(f: string[]) => void`: it wasn't able to narrow down the type of one variable, depending on another. I think this is a limitation and I can't think of any way to fix this for now. I may be wrong, but I've encountered this situation before in a bit more complex context and had to make changes to the design of the function to make it work.

I think in this case you can just do `t([file] as any)` and `t(file as any)`, finally, the point of these types is to force calling function in the correct way. If it's called correctly, then inside it knows what to do, I think it's worth adding a couple of `any`s here.

Also you could use overloads to get rid of generics, but it doesn't solve the issue:

```
function callback(b: true, t: (f: string[]) => void): void
function callback(b: false, t: (f: string) => void): void
function callback(b: boolean, t: ((f: string) => void)) | ((f: string[]) => void)) {
  //
}
```

One solution that would actually not need `any`s is to use objects, but this is not ideal, because you may need to change other logic in your application:

```
type Options = {
  b: true
  t: (f: string[]) => void
} | {
  b: false
  t: (f: string) => void
}

function callback(options: Options) {
  const file = 'file'
  if(options.b) options.t([file])
  else options.t(file)
```

Comment: Yeah I think the object way is the way to go. This function is new to my application, and if it wasn't, that wouldn't be a problem because TS would show me all the places I need to change it :). Will explore overloads a bit more too. Thank you!