# Narrowing types does not seem to work with sibling properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following type:

```js
type Props = {
  type: 'foo';
  value: string;
} | {
  type: 'baz';
  value: number;
};
```

When using `switch` with `type`, typescript thinks `value` is `string | number`.

```js
function doThing(props: Props) {
  const { type, value } = props;

  switch(type) {
  case 'foo':
    return value.length;
  case 'baz':
    return value.toExponential(); // <-- Fails because value is `string | number`.
  }
}
```

Is it possible for type narrowing to work in this scenario?

Comment: This code has several typos in it, and when I fix those, I cannot reproduce your error.  [See this](https://tsplay.dev/mq8ArN).  Please make sure your code constitutes a [mcve] so that someone can help you.  Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, I was copy/pasting from my actual problem and trying to minimize code. I should have tested it with the TS Playground. I've fixed the code and the problem is [still there](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbwFBSqSALigHIAzBBEgblygDcBDAGwFcJjlg4BLAOwDmtAL5QAPljoEOpAEaMAXjTpM2MvqwC2siHBG1sZVnwDGwHgj5QAJggAqAC34CAFGEQpi8JMgCUkvBNLLixpABoGFnZRDHcfAzxkAHceYBMHF2l-HEDGZGhyShJCOjw4CGBWOCtVdgA6ZghBYAdaXPy5RWLSqHLK6si1OuAEAFEADzBLJvMWF19qKAB6JagAHgBaDagAMUYeZlQdE0ZWDtroHlQAAy5eQXEoDW1da7q6YWxPoA) and I believe it's because of destructuring.

Comment: Now that I know what to look for, I found a duplicate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59786104/how-to-make-discriminated-unions-work-with-destructuring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is caused by destructuring `props`. It seems TypeScript can't properly narrow the types when doing that.  [This works fine](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbwFBSqSALigHIAzBBEgblygDcBDAGwFcJjlg4BLAOwDmtAL5QAPljoEOpAEaMAXjTpM2MvqwC2siHBG1sZVnwDGwHgj5QAJggAqAC34CAFGEQpi8JMgCUkvGQAdx5gEwc3D2QAOml-HDwTRmRockoSQjo8OAhgVjgrdx9o1XZo5ghBYAdaROTU+SVMvGzc-MKokpYy4AQAUQAPMEtK8xYXX1qoYWxhIA):

```js
type Props = {
  type: 'foo';
  value: string;
} | {
  type: 'baz';
  value: number;
};

function doThing(props: Props) {
  switch(props.type) {
  case 'foo':
    return props.value.length;
  case 'baz':
    return props.value.toExponential();
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug with TypeScript or just the way TypeScript treats destructured objects.  I'll have a look in their repo and report a bug if necessary.