# How to conditionally call different optional function props in a React TypeScript component without getting compiler error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React TypeScript component which accepts multiple props of which some are optional and these include functions as well. Below is a rough example of what my actual code looks like

```
interface AnimalProps {
  animalName: string;
  bark?: () => void;
  swim?: () => void;
}

const Animal = ({ animalName, bark, swim }: AnimalProps) => {
  /* some rendering here */
}
```

I also call the bark or swim function depending upon the `animalName`.
The issue is since both of these are optional props, typescript keeps throwing the error
`Cannot invoke an object which is possibly undefined`. How can I assert to the compiler that at least one of these function will definitely be passed depending upon the `animalName` ?

Comment: put a if check for `bark`  like ` if(bark){bark()}` ,same for swim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the suggested solutions, you may also use [discriminating unions: link to the doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) which is designed specifically to solve this kind of situations (refer the doc).

like this:

```js
type DogProps = {
  animalName: "dog";
  bark: () => void;
}

type FishProps = {
  animalName: "fish";
  swim: () => void;
}

type AnimalProps = DogProps | FishProps;

const Animal = (props: AnimalProps) => {
  if(props.animalName === 'dog') {
      props.bark();
  } else {
      props.swim();
  }
}
```

TS Playground link: https://tsplay.dev/NddryN

---

Destructing isn't possible until you narrow down the type like this (you see other props resolve appropriately without hassle of checking):

```js
type DogProps = {
  animalName: "dog";
  bark: () => void;
  dogProp: string;
}

type FishProps = {
  animalName: "fish";
  swim: () => void;
  fishProp: number;
}

type AnimalProps = DogProps | FishProps;

const Animal1 = (props: AnimalProps) => {
  if(props.animalName === 'dog') {
     const { bark, dogProp } = props;
      bark();
  } else {
    const {swim, fishProp} = props;
      swim();
  }
}
```

see this: https://tsplay.dev/N9pn7w

Comment: I wanted to use this initially, but couldn't get it to work if I destructure the props. Is there a way to get it working with destructuring?

Comment: I don't think destructuring works unless you narrow down the type; [See discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59786104/how-to-make-discriminated-unions-work-with-destructuring). The benefit of this approach becomes visible when you have multiple fields and you don't have check if they are `undefined` once you narrowed down the type... see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if the `function` exists before calling it.

```js
if (animalName === 'dog' && typeof bark === 'function') {
  bark();
}
```

If you feel like that is too verbose, you can also take advantage of optional-chaining to do the same thing.

```js
if (animalName === 'dog') {
  bark?.(); // Will only invoke bark() if it's defined
}
```

[Optional-chaining is supported in TypeScript since version 3.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining).

Comment: This worked for the function prop. Thanks much. Meanwhile, how can I do something similar for an optional variable prop where I cannot chain it ?