# Why Typescript cannot infer discriminated types when destructing

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, type-inference

I try in vain to narrow discriminated types with object destructuring. I thought Typescript is able to infer them since [v4.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/#cfa-aliased-conditions).

However, I [cannot do it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?importHelpers=true&module=1&keyofStringsOnly=false#code/C4TwDgpgBA6gTgS2AQwEYBsICUIGMD2cAJlALxQDeAsAFBT1QDO+AthAGIITpEBcUAcmQDaAX1q1QkKDmRF8AO3QgcBYmUq0GUfMAAWEOJ259BqETXE1J4aPCRpMG6nQZwIcxcv4AzZOkYIAG4xKAAyWEQUDGw8QiIQ6xopaFl5JRBnLTcPdO8oYDgAV2DQiLSvFTjiRNoIAA8wQmAC2xlqogAFOHwwRg0KjKgAH0iHGIlktvYFDQAKMB6+-lV47t7GAEoyAD4oADd8BCJJggVGFp8Ffhn5iih3TwyAGigAOg-FjahRbdI9lzaRgAdyQuD0UDmjzyIG2gO0DFwyECBWKEF42QRCLOFweuUqAGEDLgANYrfEZVbqchfPqYrEMVCPEmJBlQJEovwBdH0tk4lrAqKOCBEvBksbRTBUkg0paMXkMpkeEn0qxiIA) in this code (just an example of idea):

```
type WritableRecord = {
    someField: 'a'
}

type ReadonlyRecord = {
    otherField: 'b'
}

type Writable = {
    readonly: false;
} & WritableRecord;

type Readonly = {
    readonly: true;
} & ReadonlyRecord;

export type RecordProps = Readonly | Writable

type Fn = (props: RecordProps) => void

const fn: Fn = ({ readonly, ...props }) => {
    switch (readonly) {
        case true:
            const readonlyCheck: ReadonlyRecord = props

            break;
        case false:
            const writableCheck: WritableRecord = props
            break
    }
}
```

But without destructuring [it works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?importHelpers=true&module=1&keyofStringsOnly=false#code/C4TwDgpgBA6gTgS2AQwEYBsICUIGMD2cAJlALxQDeAsAFBT1QDO+AthAGIITpEBcUAcmQDaAX1q1QkKDmRF8AO3QgcBYmUq0GUfMAAWEOJ259BqETXE1J4aPCRpMG6nQZwIcxcv4AzZOkYIAG4xKAAyWEQUDGw8QiIQ6xopaFl5JRBnLTcPdO8oYDgAV2DQiLSvFTjiRNoIAA8wQmAC2xlqogAFOHwwRg0KjKgAH0iHGIlktvYFDQAKMB6+-lV47t7GAEoyAD4oADd8BCJJggVGFp8Ffhn5xY3t0j2XbUYAdyRcPSgFpcYAOncngy2xe2gYuGQgQKxQgvGy4PBYMRKKgZwulCgQLyIAANFB-oTsZV1n0oKINPc+gjUeD0S1iRkAMIGXAAaxWuUqq3U5EZylJjBptIYqCBbMSIvoVkmqMh0L8AThwpRyKl9HpmP5eIJhLeUUcEEF5MpfxVIs1+vGmBZeA5Y2imB5JHIVsdRrNrnV9DFHgl5vBVm0VlEQA):

```
type WritableRecord = {
    someField: 'a'
}

type ReadonlyRecord = {
    otherField: 'b'
}

type Writable = {
    readonly: false;
} & WritableRecord;

type Readonly = {
    readonly: true;
} & ReadonlyRecord;

export type RecordProps = Readonly | Writable

type Fn = (props: RecordProps) => void

const fn: Fn = (props) => {
    switch (props.readonly) {
        case true:
            {
                const { readonly, ...readonlyProps } = props
                const readonlyCheck: ReadonlyRecord = readonlyProps
                break;
            }


        case false:
            {
                const { readonly, ...writableProps } = props
                const writableCheck: WritableRecord = writableProps
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

Maybe, I get v4.4 announcement wrong, or is there an error?

Comment: You say "destruction" in here where you mean "destructuring".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've just discovered that currently (as of TS4.7) there's no support for control flow analysis for destructured *rest elements*.  This is a known missing feature of TypeScript, requested at [microsoft/TypeScript#46680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46680).

If you want to see this supported you might want to go to that issue and give it a , but it probably won't have much effect one way or the other.   For now you probably need to destructure the rest element only *after* checking the discriminant property, as you've done in your second example.